# Processes hierarchy

Tags: c, fork

I have a question about fork() and exit() to prepare for an exam.
In the following code, how many processes are generated and what is their hierarchy (parent/child)?

```
int i;
pid_t f;
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
  f = fork();
  if(f==0) exit(0);
  f = fork();
  if(f > 0) exit(0);
}
```

I think that the total processes created are equal to 6, but the total processes at the end are equal to 1 and the remaining one is a child, am I right or not?

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Comment: This is all unsynchronized, so the last surviving process could be the original, or a child, or a grandchild, etc.

Comment: not yet, I'm not exacly sure if my answer is correct or not

Comment: but it ends with if(f >0) exit(0)  so the original is destroyed no?

Comment: Yes, 6 processes.  The last process created is a great-grandchild of the original.  You can't be 100% sure of when the various child processes exit relative to other processes.  Since there's no output from any of the processes, you'd be hard pressed to tell the order in which they exit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There's no IPC or `wait` or anything like that. In principle any of the processes could be scheduled to run to completion first.

Comment: @melpomene: yeah — I removed that comment as you added your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i;
pid_t f;
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
  f = fork();
  if(f==0) exit(0);
  f = fork();
  if(f > 0) exit(0);
}
```

Let's draw a picture

```
P: first parent
i = 0;

+---+
| P |
+---+
  | fork()    +----+   exits
  |---------> | C1 |  ----> because of (if==0) exit(0)
  |           +----+
  |
  | fork()    +----+
  |---------> | C2 |
  |           +----+
  |             |  next loop
  |             |  i = 1, C2 is the only surviving
  |             |  process, it becomes the new parent P
  |             v
  v             repeat same graph where P == C2
 exits
 because of
 if(f > 0) exit(0)
```

Every iteration creates 2 children, the parent `P` and the first child `C_1` exits, the
second child `C_2` survives. The next iteration does the same, the new parant is the
second child of the first iteration `C_2`, it will also create two new children:
`C_2_1` and `C_2_2`. `C_2` and `C_2_1` exit and `C_2_2` survives. The next
iteration does the same, `C_2_2` creates two children: `C_2_2_1` and `C_2_2_2`.
`C_2_2` and `C_2_2_1` exit and `C_2_2_2` survives. The loop ends:

- 6 children were created: `C_1`, `C_2`, `C_2_1`, `C_2_2`, `C_2_2_1`, `C_2_2_2`
- From those children `C_2`, `C_2_2` created new children
- 3 parent process in total, 1 grandparant (`P`) and two parents (`C_2`, `C_2_2`).

The graph without the comments

```
+---+
| P |  i == 0
+---+
  |      +-----+
  |----> | C_1 | --> exit
  |      +-----+
  |
  |      +-----+
  |----> | C_2 |  i == 1, new Parent
  |      +-----+
  v         |       +-------+
 exit       |---->  | C_2_1 | --> exit
            |       +-------+
            |
            |       +-------+
            |---->  | C_2_2 | i == 2, new Parent
            |       +-------+
            |           |        +---------+
            |           |------> | C_2_2_1 | --> exit
            v           |        +---------+
          exit          |
                        |        +---------+
                        |------> | C_2_2_2 | i == 3, ends loop
                        |        +---------+
                        |
                        v
                      exit
```

Comment: Makes sense, I think you got it!

Comment: Please note that this graph represents only what's happening with the `fork`s, it doesn't tell you when exactly a process is schedule by the OS, and when it exits, the order might change between executions of your program.